# How to transform an array into a nested array in Ruby to populate a select box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I convert this array

```
['h', 'b']
```

into this array

```
[['Home', 'h'], ['Business', 'b']]
```

in Ruby?

I need this to populate a select box with values saved in the database.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: How to retrieve the values in the database? I mean, which model, which attributes, etc.

Comment: You cannot. Ruby cannot guess that 'h' stands for 'Home' and 'b' stands for 'Business'. Ruby cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is not clear. Assuming you have two arrays. You can do like below

```
    x=[1,2]  => [1, 2] 
    y=["a","b"]  => ["a", "b"] 

    x.zip y   => [[1, "a"], [2, "b"]]
```

Comment: Good example! @checkit `+1` to you.